# Inside the Linux kernel, does the `nice` priority level of a task get modified anywhere else beside these cases?

Tags: linux-kernel

From within the Linux kernel, I want to overwrite the `nice` priority (with a hardcoded value) of all regular processes (e.g. of the scheduling class `SCHED_NORMAL`) that have an uneven process ID.

I discovered that the default settings of a process are initiated in [/source/init/init_task.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.13/source/init/init_task.c), including the priority value which is set to default value `MAX_PRIO - 20` (i.e., `120`), as can be seen in the definition of the struct definition of `init_task`.

My reasoning is that if I were to modify these default settings in `init_task.c`, it should cover all cases with exception to any users calling the system call `sys_setpriority` (by using the `nice` command for example). Is this correct, or are there any other cases where the task's `prio` may be modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I discovered that the default settings of a process are initiated in /source/init/init_task.c

No. That's the definition of the `init` task itself, it's not used to init[ialize] new tasks. The init task is the first userspace task that is ran by the kernel upon startup, and its `task_struct` is hardcoded for performance and ease of use. Any other task is created through [`fork(2)`](https://manned.org/fork.2)/[`clone(2)`](https://manned.org/clone.2).

> My reasoning is that if I were to modify these default settings in init_task.c, it should cover all cases

It doesn't cover anything really, just the initial priority of `init`, which can very well overwrite it itself since it runs as `root`.

---

The priority of a task can be changed in different ways, but the kernel should not "automatically" change priority of tasks, at least ***to my knowledge***.

Therefore, if you want to "control" the priority in such a way, your best bet would be to change the code of `fork` (specifically [`clone_process()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/kernel/fork.c#L1841)), since forking is the only way to create new processes in Linux.

Other than that, there are other syscalls that can end up modifying the priority of a process. Taking a quick glance at the kernel code, at least [`sched_setscheduler`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) ([source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L5313)), [`sched_setparam`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setparam.2.html) ([source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L5328)), and [`setpriority`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setpriority) ([source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/kernel/sys.c#L197)).

Comment: Excellent answer, really. You have a thorough understanding of Linux. I should've remembered that fork() creates all the processes from the init process. I will try to patch down the syscalls you mentioned, if they happen to modify the priority of my user processes. What I'm trying to do is quite ridiculous, but it's for a homework assignment, not a real world application.